# Не записывает в базу и не выводит на страницы кирилицу. Как перевести всё в UTF-8?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

У меня весь проект на Spring. В общем в базу (MySQL) ине хочет записывать русские буквы (проблема именно в классах и методах) и выводить на страницы русский текст. Как исправить?

P,S, Maven настроен на UTF-8.

Comment: Попробуйте конструировать строки так: new String(bytearray, "UTF-8");

Comment: Тут слишком много мест, где может что-то пойти не так. Например, как вы к БД подключаетесь, с какими настройками?

Comment: Maven - просто сборщик. Надо смотреть какая кодировка подразумевается при коннекте к БД, в какой кодировке сами таблицы БД, в какой кодировке в эту таблицу передавались данные (помню весёлое время, когда мне достались таблицы в cp1251 полныя строк в utf8, бывало и наоборот), в какой кодировке передаются страницы с формами (веб интерфейс), в какой кодировке отправляет строки скрипт с клиентской стороны (или просто форма) в сторону сервиса.

Comment: Подключаюсь через hibernate:     <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/table</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>